# getTime() not working with Qt

Tags: javascript, qt, qt4.8

I have the following javascript code working fine in the browser but not in Qt:

```js
var now = new Date()
var then = new Date("2013-12-08T00:10:01Z")
var timeDiff = then.getTime() - now.getTime()
alert(timeDiff)
```

When I run the same code in Qt `timeDiff` returns as `NaN`. Does anyone know why Javascript `.getTime()` is behaving differently in the Qt environment?

**Update**

Even the following is returning invalid date

```
console.log(new Date("2013-12-08"))
```

Might be related to the following question:

[new Date("YYYY-MM-DD") stopped working in Qt WebKit after removing MacPorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098731/new-dateyyyy-mm-dd-stopped-working-in-qt-webkit-after-removing-macports)

*Note: I'm running the Qt on a BlackBerry 10 device hooked up to computer for debugging, not actually running the Qt program on my Mac.*

Comment: What do then.getTime() and now.getTime() return respectively, in Qt (QML?) and "normal conditions" (which means what?)?

Comment: now.getTime() returns 1386286256169 and then.getTime() returns NaN. By normal conditions I mean within a web browser rather then in Qt/QML

Comment: Seems 'then' returns 'Invalid Date' but only within the QT enviornment